# Склонение слова "пустельга"

Tags: морфология

Пустельга - это такая хищная птица. В единственном числе - понятно. А во множественном, как я понимаю, - пустельги? Но вот совершенно не могу образовать форму родительного падежа множественного числа. По идее, должно быть "пустельг", но как-то это не звучит.
Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно образовать форму родительного падежа множественного числа от слова "пустельга"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пустельг, как говорит Зализняк